# Mongoose: Remove elements from array of objects in Mongo if condition is met

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects that stores the date of an API request along with the JSON values of the request and response. The issue is I don't want this log to get massive. I need to set a max limit or remove entries older than a particular date.

I'm trying to use a mongo / mongoose query to delete elements of an array when the date value of that object is greater than 5 days.

This is the relevant section the mongo model:

```
      log: [
        {
          select: false,
          date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
            select: false
          },
          request: { type: String, select: false },
          response: { type: String, select: false }
        }
      ]
```

I've tried using updateMany and $pull

```
    const fiveDaysAgo = moment()
      .subtract(5, 'day')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    // Ensure log value exists in collection
    // Remove any log entry older than five days
    Collection.updateMany(
      { log: { $exists: true } },
      { $pull: { 'log.$[].date': { $gte: fiveDaysAgo } } }
    ).then(data => console.log(data));
```

This produces this error:

```
(node:1957) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value
```

If there was a way to set a max value of entires in the array of objects, and automatically pop the oldest entry off when the new entry is inserted that would also work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your schema `log` is just an array of documents which contain a field `date` so if you want to build a condition for that field your update can look like below:

```
Collection.updateMany(
    { log: { $exists: true } },
    { $pull: { 'log': { date: { $lte: fiveDaysAgo } } } }
    ).then(...)
```

Comment: Shoot, wanted to answer the same ;-).

Comment: @BenSower you can always upvote if you think it is the correct answer ;)

Comment: NEVER! Nah, just kidding, but with people like you, how is a poor newbie like me going to get them sweet upvotes in the first place? :-P

Comment: This is very close, except it deleted every entry in logs. Not just things older than five days.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor `$gte` will remove newer that five days ago so you need `$lte`