# Delete objects that met a condition inside an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection has array "name" with objects inside. I need to remove only those objects inside array where "name.x" is blank.

```
"name": [
    {
      "name.x": [
        {
          "_id": "607e7fcca57aa56e2a06b57b",
          "name": "abc",
          "type": "123"
        }
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62232cd70ce38c5007de31e6"
      },
  "qty": "1.0",
  "Unit": "pound,lbs"
},
{
  "name.x": [
    {
      "_id": "607e7fcca57aa56e2a06b430",
      "name": "xyz",
      "type": "123"
    }
  ],
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62232cd70ce38c5007de31e7"
  },
  "qty": "1.0",
  "Unit": "pound,lbs"
},{
  "name.x": []
  ,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62232cd70ce38c5007de31e7"
  },
  "qty": "1.0",
  "Unit": "pound,lbs"
}
```

I tried to get all the ids where name.x is blank using python and used $pull to remove objects base on those ids.But the complete array got deleted.How can I remove the objects that meet the condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose: Remove elements from array of objects in Mongo if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115887/mongoose-remove-elements-from-array-of-objects-in-mongo-if-condition-is-met)

Comment: @SM1312 Mongoose is a Javascript only object modeler. OP's question does not specify a language so I'd assume they'd like a MongoDB lang specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think [MongoDB update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) meets your requirement especially to deal with the field name with `.`.

`$set` - Update the `name` array field by `$filter` `name.x` field is not an empty array.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      name: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$name",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $getField: {
                  field: "name.x",
                  input: "$$this"
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GglVq299XDp)